# Confused about which Vuejs files to push to NPM for a library

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs2, vue-cli-3

I am on windows, using Vuejs trying to build my own library and push to NPM.

These are my working environments:

```
$ node -v
v10.16.0

$ npm -v
6.9.0

$ vue -V
3.8.4
```

I followed [cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html) page to build my library, and finally after running:

```
vue-cli-service build --target lib --name myLib ./src/index.js
```

I can see the output just like in [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#library) or here from my output:

```
You may use special comments to disable some warnings.
Use // eslint-disable-next-line to ignore the next line.
Use /* eslint-disable */ to ignore all warnings in a file.
File                           Size                  Gzipped

dist\my-vue-lib.umd.min.js    28.90 KiB             10.02 KiB
dist\my-vue-lib.umd.js        81.10 KiB             20.21 KiB
dist\my-vue-lib.common.js     80.71 KiB             20.09 KiB

Images and other types of assets omitted.
```

The thing I don't understand is, when I push my package to NPM, do I only push these files? Or do I push the whole root of my directory (without node_modules)

Some things are not clear or mentioned in the docs, or maybe they are assumed everyone knows. But after the build process is success, do I push my entire folder to NPM?

Just to be clear, when I initialized the project I used the command

```
vue create my-vue-lib
```

and it generated everything from `readme`, `package.json`, `tests/` ... I asked this because before the new vue-cli the process was different.

So to sum it up, after the build process is success, what do I push to NPM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just push your `dist`, the rest is not needed. Create a `.npmignore` put in your `./src**` that should be ok.

Comment: Thanks, but if that is the case, then why do I see Vue libraries in github where I can see the components like `.vue` or `index.js` and `package.json`? If I only push the `dist/` then what about the rest? Can you show me also a package from github where only the dist is present?

Comment: What you are looking at in github is not necessarily what is published on npm, one is the repository which the package is made from (github) and one is the package that you use in a project (locally in the node modules you can see it)

Comment: But that is also part of process. I have to also push it to github before I could push it to NPM. (see vue-select: https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select/tree/master/src) it has the components in github for everyone to see) but once I install the package, I get the dist as well. I mean, it's hard to explain but I don't just want to push the `dist/` to github

Comment: You can exclude what you want in github with `.gitignore` and exclude from what is being published with `.npmignore` they are unrelated. When you do `git push...` it goes to github, when you ` npm publish...` it goes to the npm registry, these are different locations that do not depend on each other.